# Series convergence ques

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I was just solving another question regarding this topic and just wanna check if I am doing it right.

So the question is whether the given series converges or not, and justify.

$$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{(\ln{n})^2}{ n^2}$$

I have tried using ratio and comparison test, but that leads me nowhere.
For comparison test I compared the term with $\frac{1}{n^2}$. Am I doing that wrong?

Thank you so much :)

Comment: Compare with $\sum \frac 1 {n^{3/2}}$.

Comment: To spell out one item: it is true that $\frac{(\ln n)^2}{n^2} \ge \frac1{n^2}$ for all $n\ge3$; so if the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{n^2}$ diverged, then so would $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(\ln n)^2}{n^2}$ by the comparison test. However, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{n^2}$ does not diverge, so the comparison test doesn't help (it "goes the wrong way").

Answer (score -2, accepted):

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(ln(n))^2}{n^2}< \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{ln(n) \sqrt{n}}{n^2}<\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{ln(n)}{n^{\frac{3}{2}}}<\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{\frac{3}{2}}}$

This is a p-series with p>1 so it converges. Thus $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(ln(n))^2}{n^2}$ converges as well.

Comment: $\frac{\ln(n)}{n^{\frac{3}{2}}}$ isn't less than $n^{-\frac{3}{2}}$, though.

Answer (score 0):

Recall that $f(s) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^{-s}$ converges when $s>1$.

Then we observe that $f''(s)= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(\ln(n))^{2}}{n^s}$, with the same region of convergence.

Hence $f''(2) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(\ln(n))^{2}}{n^2}$.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a nice way
to show that,
for any $ a > 0$,
$\dfrac{\ln(x)}{x^a}
\to 0$
as
$x \to \infty$.
It actually shows that
$\dfrac{\ln(x)}{x^a}
\lt\dfrac{2}{ax^{a/2}}
$
for $x \gt 1$.

$\begin{array}\\
\ln(x)
&=\int_1^x \dfrac{dt}{t}\\
&<\int_1^x \dfrac{dt}{t^{1-c}}
\qquad\text{since } t^{1-c} < t
\text{ for }0 < c \\
&=\int_1^x t^{c-1}dt\\
&=\dfrac{t^c}{c}|_1^x\\
&=\dfrac{x^c-1}{c}\\
&<\dfrac{x^c}{c}\\
\end{array}
$

Let $c = \frac{a}{2}$,
so that
$\ln(x)
\lt \dfrac{x^{a/2}}{a/2}
= \dfrac{2x^{a/2}}{a}
$.
Dividing by $x^a$,
$\dfrac{\ln(x)}{x^a}
\lt\dfrac{2}{ax^{a/2}}
$.